# How do I extract strings used in exe file in Python?

Tags: python, file, exe

Is it possible to read exe file and extract all strings used in this exe? I need to check what kind of strings are used in some exe file, but I'm not sure that is a simple as I think - just read the file and get strings.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the linux tool **strings**

Comment: yes I know, but I need to write a program with same purpose.

Comment: allocer - why do you need to reimplement strings?

Comment: Maybe he's on windows?

Comment: This is first thing - I'm on windows. Next thing is this is a part of my bigger project. I will need also extract libs names, file size, information about locked/unlocked file, etc.